# How to store and retrieve data in python

Tags: python, database, quandl

I have been looking for answers to my questions, but haven't found a definitive answer. I am new to python, mysql, and data science, so any advice is appreciated
What I want to be able to do is:

1. use python to pull daily close data from quandl for n securities
2. store the data in a database
3. retrieve, clean, and normalize the data
4. run regressions on different pairs
5. write the results to a csv file

The pseudocode below shows in a nutshell what I want to be able to do.
The questions I have are:
How do I store the quandl data in MySQL?
How do I retrieve that data from MySQL? Do I store it into lists and use statsmodels?

```
tickers = [AAPL, FB, GOOG, YHOO, XRAY, CSCO]
qCodes = [x + 'WIKI/' for x in tickers]
for i in range(0, len(qCodes)):
    ADD TO MYSQLDB->Quandl.get(qCodes[i], collapse='daily', start_date=start, end_date=end)

for x in range(0, len(qCodes)-1):
    for y in range(x+1, len(qCodes)):
        //GET FROM MYSQLDB-> x, y 
        //clean(x,y)
        //normalize(x,y)
        //write to csv file->(regression(x,y))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice library called `MySQLdb` in Python, which helps you interact with the MySQL db's. So, for the following to execute successfully, you have to have your python shell and the MySQL shells fired up.

**How do I store the quandl data in MySQL?**

```
import MySQLdb

#Setting up connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", user_name, password, db_name)

cursor = db.cursor()

#Inserting records into the employee table
sql = """INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, INCOME) VALUES('Steven', "Karpinski", "50", "M", "43290")"""

try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
except:
   db.rollback()
db.close()
```

I did it for custom values. So, for quandl data, create the schema in a similar way and store them by executing a loop.

**How do I retrieve that data from MySQL? Do I store it into lists and use statsmodels?**

For data retrieval, you execute the following command, similar to the above command.

```
sql2 = """SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
        """
try:
   cursor.execute(sql2)
   db.commit()
except:
   db.rollback()

result = cursor.fetchall()
```

The `result` variable now contains the result of the query inside `sql2` variable, and it is in form of tuples.

So, now you can convert those tuples into a data structure of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Quandl has a python package that makes interacting with the site trivial.

From Quandl's [python page](https://www.quandl.com/help/python):

```
import Quandl
mydata = Quandl.get("WIKI/AAPL")
```

By default, Quandl's package returns a pandas dataframe. You can use Pandas to manipulate/clean/normalize your data as you see fit and use Pandas to upload the data directly to a [sql database](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) :

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
engine = sql.create_engine('mysql://name:blah@location/testdb')
mydata.to_sql('db_table_name', engine, if_exists='append')
```

To get the data back from your database, you can also use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sql
engine = sql.create_engine('mysql://name:blah@location/testdb')
query = sql.text('''select * from quandltable''')
mydata = pd.read_sql_query(engine, query)
```

After using statsmodels to run your analyses, you can use either pandas' `df.to_csv()` method or numpy's `savetxt()` function. (Sorry, i cannot post the links for those functions; I don't have enough reputation yet!)